# getting issue with conversion from string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I am getting issue while converting string to DateTime.

The value I am receiving as "08-26-2015 10:14:57.898Z".

I am trying to convert the above string to DateTime.

My Code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(element.Value,"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Exception:
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: What's your current culture?

Comment: @juharr -Even i tried with CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,i am getting same exception.My current culture ="en-US"

Comment: Then the problem is the date separator.  For US and Invaiant it's a slash `/` and not a dash `-`.  As others have mentioned you might want to use `DateTime.Parse` or `Convert.ToDateTime` instead or specify that you want dashes as the separator in the format.  Also you need to specify the milliseconds and the Z at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have string with different format than you trying for conversion.

Try this

```
var input = "08-26-2015 10:14:57.898Z";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Better to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, in case the current culture is using a time separator other than colon (:)

Comment: @Joe Thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("08-26-2015 10:14:57.898Z", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`(or null) the slash `/` has a special meaning. It is replaced with the current culture's date separator. Since that is not `-` but `/` in US you get an exception.  [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#dateSeparator)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Convert.ToDateTime ?
I just tried with your string and it works fine :

```
var s = "08-26-2015 10:14:57.898Z";
var date = Convert.ToDateTime(s);
```

Comment: --Still facing issue,tried with X-TECh solution and it worked

Comment: Happy to know you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "08-26-2015 10:14:57.898Z";
DateTime date;
DateTime.TryParse (s, out date);
```

Now `date` variable contains DateTime value you need.